# How can I create a list of objects from data in an enum?

Tags: c#, enums

My application has this code

```
var result = await db.ContentTypes
   .Select(e => new
   {
      Id = e.ContentTypeId,
      Name = e.Name
   })
   .AsNoTracking()
   .ToListAsync();
```

It gets data from a SQL Server table and creates a list of objects with `Id` and `Name`. This works well and I use it to get reference data from many tables.

However there is one data collection that is stored in an Enum:

```
public enum ERole { 
    Super         = 0,
    Admin         = 1,
    ....
    Guest         = 8
}
```

I know I could hard code a solution but rather than have two hardcoded structures holding role information.

How can I get the data from the enum and make it into a list with an Id and Name just like I do with Content Types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I get this correctly you want something like this:

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(ERole))
    .Cast<ERole>()
    .Select(x => new { Id = (int)x, Name = x.ToString() })
    .ToList();
```